# XQuartz, xterm and shell errors

Tags: terminal, x11

A am using bash as a default shell.

If I execute `xterm` (which is opened in XQuartz), I get the following errors:

```
bash: unsetenv: command not found
bash: unsetenv: command not found
bash: setenv: command not found
bash: setenv: command not found
bash: setenv: command not found
bash: setenv: command not found
bash: setenv: command not found
bash: unsetenv: command not found
```

It seems that a configuration file for csh is sourced.

If I execute `xterm` again in the `xterm` window, I get a new window without any errors.

In my home directory I have nothing with `setenv` or `unsetenv`

In both cases (from the terminal or from xterm):

```
$ type xterm
xterm is /opt/local/bin/xterm
```

Which file is read? Why only on the first execution?

Comment: How do you execute the first `xterm`?

Comment: @nohillside either from the terminal or from the menu of XQuartz. In both ways something is executed. If I execute it from xterm itself then it's OK. In both cases I execute the same binary (/opt/local/bin/xterm)

Comment: What does `type xterm` in Bash say?

Comment: ```xterm is /opt/local/bin/xterm``` (I updated the question)

Comment: Interesting. I have xterm in /opt/X11/bin, as part of Xquartz. Is the one in local a link, a script, the same binary as in /opt/X11/bin?

Comment: ```/opt/X11/bin/xterm``` produces the same result

Comment: You are running `bash` as your login shell. There seems to be a problem with your bash environment at login and not at next calls. This difference might come simply from the fact that these 2  are different ( ex. `/bin/bash` ≠ `/opt/bin/bash` ) or that you have a bug within `~/.bash_profile`. Which one is your `bash` at login ( in `/etc/passwd` ) and the next ones ( `type bash` )?
Could you check that your `~/.bash_profile` doesn't source a C-shell script?

Comment: @dan ```.bash_profile``` just sources ```.bashrc``` if it exists.

Comment: Which `bash` is your login shell?
Which one does `xterm` see? What's the output from 1st `xterm` and next one of the command: `type bash`?

Comment: @dan login shell is ```/opt/local/bin/bash``` and in both cases the output of ```type bash``` is ```/opt/local/bin/bash```

Comment: Let's try another track: which C-shell script is used from your 1st `bash` leading to your 8 error messages? Hint to find it:
`find . -atime -1m`

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs when the used shell (in `$SHELL`) is not listed in `/etc/shells`.

From the man page:

> Xterm validates shell programs by finding their pathname in the text file /etc/shells.  It treats the environment variable “SHELL”
> specially because (like “TERM”), xterm both reads and updates the variable, and because the program started by xterm is not necessarily
> a shell.

I am using bash 5 installed via MacPorts (`/opt/local/bin/bash`).

Adding it to `/etc/shells` solves the problem.

Comment: By default `xterm` runs `/bin/sh` which is `/bin/bash` when the SHELL is not defined or the passwd defined shell is not a valid one.
But `/bin/bash` shouldn't give you errors like these coming from a C-shell script. This remains a serious pb to analyze.

Comment: @dan I agree. And even if a [tc]sh shell was executed I don't get why it should read my .bashrc file ....

Comment: Is `/opt/local/bin/bash` your login shell?

Comment: @dan yes it's my login shell